# Need a log management tool which displays logs from all servers(connected locally) and also shows some metrics of APM

Tags: logs

Currently we were maintaining all application logs in the file. If we run our application on multi-server environment all the logs will spread over different servers. In case of debugging we need to check the logs in all servers which is difficult task.

Can some one suggest me good log management tool to show some stats and centralize the logs in all servers to the same place?

Comment: What OS do the servers run?

Comment: Are you OK with command-line? If not, what UI do you want?

Comment: It can run on both windows and linux servers. What do you mean by 'what UI' ?

Comment: Here I am looking for a third party management tool(with UI) with which I can view or manage all the logs in different servers at common place.

Comment: Are you OK with installing SSH servers on all servers? Or any other kind of agent?

Comment: "What UI" : Do you want to be able to scroll with your mouse? Do you need search? Do you need to coloring/filtering, for instance to see errors in red?

Comment: Yeah I need all those features on the third party software

Comment: Then edit your question to add this information, we can't help you without it. Most log solutions are command-line-based do not support mouse operations.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running unix, linux, or any of the BSD variants, your logging facility is syslog.  In it you can log to a syslog daemon on another host.

Mac is mostly unix under the hood, but apple has hacked it a lot.  It may or may not work.

Windows?  havn't a sniff.

There's another program, netcat, that in effect constructs a network pipe.  Log to a file.  Point netcat with one end watching the file, and the other end sending data to a host.

See https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=netcat&manpath=SuSE+Linux/i386+11.3

Note that for timestamps to make sense, you need to have everyone agreeing what time it is.  If you don't already, run ntpd on all your machines, and configure one to sync to some time standard, and broadcast time to your local network.

You also may need to do some data massaging to get finer time granularity.  Most timestamps are only to the second.  If you are logging multiple services from multiple hosts, you want a strict time sequence.